# How to encrypt whole disk?

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems, disk

I would like to write application (as background service) which will encrypt whole file system totally. The questions are:

1. Is it possible, such that all Android services will work smoothly? Like, say Microsoft's BitLocker?
2. If so - can someone point me to some sources/docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible thought the API.

You'd have to get the [source code](http://s.android.com) of Android and try to implement that yourself baking your own custom system image.

However I don't think it is possible at all.

Comment: I thought we can implement full disk encryption in Android by following the steps in this link - http://source.android.com/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html? Can you give any guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

Encrypted file system would be possible only via kernel-mode driver, which means a custom ROM for a device.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if you are doing this to be secure, or only in order for a trojan to claim payment for restoring the files ;)

Encrypting files after they have been written in plaintext will leave the plaintext spread around your Flash (or disk) until that space is later reclaimed for new files.  Its basically not secure.  You have to encrypt before bytes get written to disk.

Android runs on Linux, and device drivers for storage, whilst modular, are compiled into the kernel.  So unless you are distributing a custom Android image, you cannot post-install install a driver on someone's device.

There has been discussion like this on the mailing list [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-kernel@googlegroups.com/msg01200.html).